# Magento 2 How to create order on user demand

Tags: php, knockoutjs, jquery

Hi I have one requirement where user visit on the website and upload their product image(Like some tool image, Some kind of machinery part etc.) and select some attribute like size,colour,material etc and click on add to cart price will dynamic calculate. No preselected product is there customer demand for product.
Magento has to detect product based on image.
User place the order.
Please advice how can i achieve this.
NOTE: This is not work of product customisation.

Comment: Try to be more specific, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Pretty sure your real problem is not about creating order, but to search for products based on images, like Google Images search, or similar feature implemented on other giant e-commerce platforms like Aliexpress. If that is the case, I would say it is easier to do it outside of Magento, meaning you will have an external server responsible for image search algorithm, Magento will simply make API calls to that server and receive response: result products.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by giangvdm , the main problem is here to detect the product using the image the customer is uploading.
You can check this module by [Webkul](https://store.webkul.com/magento2-image-product-search.html) or this free [one](https://github.com/ReggieTe/magento-image-search) from Github.
You can check how they are detecting product with images, and implement the same on your module.